# Writing a file then zipping file and download on submit

Tags: php, file, download, zip

I am trying to create a file (works), zip a file (works), and download. But when I put it in the order I think is correct I get a warning saying **headers already sent**

My code is:

```
//TOP Writes to file -this works
$handle=fopen('db_backup.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$end);
fclose($handle);

//Creates zip -this works
$zip   =array('db_backup.sql');
create_zip($zip,'db_backup.zip',true);
ob_clean();
flush();

//Download the zip get the headers already sent message
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=db_backup.zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('db_backup.zip'));
readfile('db_backup.zip');
unlink($zip_file);
```

But if I move  headers to TOP I do not get the message. But the zip is empty!

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=db_backup.zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('db_backup.zip'));

//TOP Writes to file -this works
$handle=fopen('db_backup.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$end);
fclose($handle);

//Creates zip -this works
$zip   =array('db_backup.sql');
create_zip($zip,'db_backup.zip',true);
ob_clean();
flush();

//Download the zip get the headers already sent message

readfile('db_backup.zip');
unlink($zip_file);
```

Comment: What's the full output from the script, are there any warnings? Do you have any characters before the opening tag in your file? Did you save the script as UTF-8 (try ASCII)?

Comment: When you say script does that meant the file created?